# I want to create an array with number of objects that is equal to the number of obj in plants array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

After forEach loop the object values changes in all the indexes, how to limit it with the current index

```
 resp = {
        label:'flowers',
        plants: [
          {
            plantLabel: 'rose',
            plantCode: 'RS',
          },
          {
            plantLabel: 'Jasmine',
            plantCode: 'JAS',
          },
          {
            plantLabel: 'Lotus',
            plantCode: 'LU',
          }
        ]
      };

  loop() {
    let newArray = [];
    let tempResp = this.resp;
    const val = chunk(tempResp.plants, 1);
    console.log(val);
    val.forEach(plant => {
      let pushValue = tempResp;
      pushValue.plants= plant;
      newArray.push(pushValue);
    });
    **//expected 
    // [
    //   {
    //     label:'flowers',
    //     plants: [
    //       {
    //         plantLabel: 'rose',
    //         plantCode: 'RS',
    //       }
    //     ]
    //   },{
    //     label:'flowers',
    //     plants: [
    //       {
    //         plantLabel: 'Jasmine',
    //         plantCode: 'JAS',
    //       }
    //     ]
    //   },{
    //     label:'flowers',
    //     plants: [
    //       {
    //         plantLabel: 'Lotus',
    //         plantCode: 'LU',
    //       }
    //     ]
    //   }
    // ]**
```

But am getting results as

```
// [
    //   {
    //     label:'flowers',
    //     plants: [
    //       {
    //          plantLabel: 'Lotus',
    //         plantCode: 'LU',
    //       }
    //     ]
    //   },{
    //     label:'flowers',
    //     plants: [
    //       {
    //          plantLabel: 'Lotus',
    //         plantCode: 'LU',
    //       }
    //     ]
    //   },{
    //     label:'flowers',
    //     plants: [
    //       {
    //         plantLabel: 'Lotus',
    //         plantCode: 'LU',
    //       }
    //     ]
    //   }
    // ]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are the expected and actual output unnecessarily commented?

Comment: What has the title _"I want to create an array with number of objects..."_ to do with the _"...the object values changes in all the indexes, how to limit it with the current index"_ in the body of the question?

Comment: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Please add the curly bracket to end the `loop` function. What is in the `chunk` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map over the original plants and use the label.

```js
let newArray = resp.plants.map((plant) => ({
    label: resp.label,
    plant,
});
```

The reason you get that result is that you shallow copy the object, Any change to that variable will affect the original variable.